# Finding the least rational $r>0$ such that $\prod_{n=0}^3(2\cos(2^n\pi r)-1)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Earlier a friend showed me a tricky problem he needed help with. I was able to find a possible solution but I've been unable to check it.

> Find the least rational $r>0$ such that $x=\pi r$ satisfies $(2\cos(8x) - 1)(2\cos(4x) - 1)(2\cos(2x) - 1)(2\cos(x) - 1)=1$

If we look for $r\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ it's clear that $\cos(2^n\pi r)=(-1)^{2^n r}$. Given that our equation is simply $$\prod_{n=0}^3(2\cos(2^n\pi r)-1)=1$$it is trivial to note that all even $r$ work. It would be *nice* then that the least solution merely be $r=2$.

Unfortunately I have no idea whether there is some $r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(1,2)$ that could potentially work. Does anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle (2\cos y+1)(2\cos y-1)=4\cos^2y-1=2(\cos2y+1)-1=2\cos2y+1,$

multiply either sides by $2\cos x+1\ne0$ as $\displaystyle\cos y=-\frac12\implies \cos2y=-\frac12$

$\displaystyle\implies \cos8x=\cos4x=\cos2x=\cos x=-\frac12 $ which does not satisfy the given equation.

Comment: Right, I could've sworn I tried this earlier... so obvious in retrospect. *doh* silly me ;-) thanks for the reminder.

Comment: In about 10 minutes I'll accept this.